# Triangle node with adjustable height

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, trees

I'm trying to draw AVL trees with TikZ, what I need is:

Binary tree with simple circle nodes, and adjustable height triangle (or rectangle)
nodes for subtrees, both containing only single characters.
Here's a picture:

[image]

I tried with rectangle and regular polygon, but they seem to be unaffected by aspect ratio...
Is there an easy way of drawing something like this in TikZ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `isosceles triangle` shape and some manually set heights:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  inner/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=7mm,inner sep=0},
  leaf/.style={isosceles triangle,draw,shape border rotate=90,isosceles triangle stretches=true, minimum height=20mm,minimum width=12mm,inner sep=0,yshift={-20mm},font=\tiny},
  large leaf/.style={leaf,minimum height=35mm,yshift={-14.5mm}},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=21mm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=14mm},
]
  \node[inner] {T}
    [child anchor=north]
    child {node[inner] {L}
      child {node[large leaf] {}}
      child {node[inner] {LR}
        child{node[leaf] {}}
        child{node[leaf] {}}}}
    child {node[large leaf] {L.Allison}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I don't know why the top vertices of the two large triangles are at different heights relative to their sibling nodes.