# How to plot a complicated multi-variable function in a tex document automatically, not just importing an image

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I have the following Tex functions and I want to plot them in my tex thesis, but I don't know how. I mean, I want the Tex to draw the function, not just to include an external image to it.

```
y[\text{x$\_$},\text{m$\_$},\text{n$\_$}]\text{:=}\text{Abs}\left[1-\left(1-\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2\right){}^{\wedge}m\right]{}^{\wedge}n;

\text{F}[\text{x$\_$},\text{m$\_$},\text{n$\_$}]\text{:=}(-y[0,m,n]+(y[0,m,n]-1)x+y[x,m,n])/(1-2y[0,m,n])

\text{Plot}[\{\text{F}[x,0.2,0.5],\text{F}[x,1,5],\text{F}[x,1,10]\},\{x,-1,1\}]
```

Comment: 3 variables function! Would not be easy!

Comment: Check out the `pgfplots` package.

Comment: Could you show the output of the Mathematica code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution by means of pgfplots + lualatex (i.e. it has to be compiled with `lualatex P.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \directlua{
        Y = function(x,m,n)
            return math.abs(1-(1-((x+1)/2)^2)^m)^n
        end
        N1 = function(x,m,n)
            return (-Y(0,m,n) + (Y(0,m,n)-1)*x + Y(x,m,n))/ (1-2*Y(0,m,n))
        end
    }
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{N1}{3}{%
        \edef\pgfmathresult{\directlua{tex.print(N1(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#2},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#3}))}}%
    }%
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        enlargelimits,
        tick align=inside,
        no markers,
        legend entries={$N1(x,0.2,0.5)$\\$N1(x,1,5)$\\$N1(x,1,10)$\\},
        domain=-1:0.99999,
        samples=150,
        minor tick num=4,
    ]
    \addplot {N1(x,0.2,0.5)};
    \addplot {N1(x,1,5)};
    \addplot {N1(x,1,10)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

some remarks:

- I have used Lua in order to benefit from its higher accuracy - the current formulation of N1 suffers from numerical instability near x=-1 (i.e. small errors in the input add up to huge errors in the output). This requires higher precision than TeX offers by means of its builtin methods.
- I ignored the possibility to reuse the value for `y(0,m,n)`. It does not hurt to compute it twice.
- Add `cycle list={dashed,black,black}` to the option list of the axis to get your plot styles - I prefered the defaylt cycle list (with `no markers`) such that you can identify each in a legend (which I added as well).
- Note that I chose to define a PGF math function `N1` by means of `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`. This allows us to use `N1(x,m,n)` inside of a PGF math expression (in particular: in `\addplot {<expression>}`). The argument `{3}` means that the new function takes three arguments, available as `#1`, `#2`, and `#3` as in a macro. Currently, these arguments are in some internal format generated by the floating point library (in TeX), so we need to convert them back to something understood by Lua (by means of `\pgfmathfloatvalueof`.
- since I never plotted `Y` directly, I did not generate a `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` for `Y` -- after all, the Lua code can compute this in a self-contained fashion.
- Note that `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` is supposed to assign results to the macro `\pgfmathresult`, which is the purpose of `\edef\pgfmathresult`. The `tex.print` is Lua's way to report results back to TeX.

---

In general, it would be safe to formulate the function by means of PGF's math engine which results in

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{Y}{3}{%
        \pgfmathparse{abs(1-(1-((#1+1)/2)^2)^(#2))^(#3)}%
    }%
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{N1}{3}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(-Y(0,#2,#3) + (Y(0,#2,#3)-1)*(#1) + Y(#1,#2,#3))/ (1-2*Y(0,#2,#3)}%
    }%
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        enlargelimits,
        tick align=inside,
        no markers,
        legend entries={$N1(x,0.2,0.5)$\\$N1(x,1,5)$\\$N1(x,1,10)$\\},
        domain=-1:0.99999,
        samples=150,
        minor tick num=4,
    ]
    \addplot {N1(x,0.2,0.5)};
    \addplot {N1(x,1,5)};
    \addplot {N1(x,1,10)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the visible artifact near x=-1; it originates in the numerically instable function formulation near x=-1 combined with TeX's limited precision (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: Is there any way to understand why this instability exists?

Comment: My hypothesis is based on the differences computed in `y(x,m,n)`. For `x=-1`, `y=0`. Near `x=-1`, it is approximately 0. In this regime, parts of N1 cancel out (at least almost entirely). My guess is that in the presence of inaccuracies, these inaccuracies do not cancel out as they should. They are magnified. But I did not proof it (and I hope that I did not claim something stupid. Let me know if you proof me wrong).  I know that TeX's precision is somewhat less than float, so this sounds plausible.

Comment: I am a little in doubt about that because in other outputs and plots, this is not seen (even outputs from other softwares). However, I think that for some m and n, this instability may occur. I will ask my advisor about this.

Comment: I am a little in doubt myself. However, keep in mind that other outputs and plots use higher precision. My guess is that the limited precision of TeX makes these "mini instabilities" visible although double precision (or perhaps single precision float) is enough to overcome it. The alternative would be a bug and/or unnecessary inaccuracy in the PGF math engine (who knows).

Comment: It may be possible to verify this by reducing the working precision on Mathematica and plot this function again to compare the two outputs.

Comment: I would appreciate that effort. Maybe we can improve the PGF math layer as a consequence.

Comment: Can I put the legend under the graph and mark the axises?

Comment: Sure. Please refer to the pgfplots manual (`texdoc pgfplots` or http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) section "Legend appearance". Axis labels can be added by means of `xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$`

Comment: Working with your answer (the first part I mean) is much easier for me than the other answers on this question. Now I am trying to fix my legend and styles.

Comment: If you encounter difficulties with my hints, you are welcome to ask new following-up questions of sorts "pgfplots: how can I position legends here/there/whatever".

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind, I posted [an answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193927/52417) to my question with a code based on your suggestion. I wanted to show how I customized the code and produced my preferred plot.

Comment: can you please explain me what does this part do? `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{N1}{3}{%\edef\pgfmathresult{\directlua{tex.print(N1(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#2},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#3}))}}` I think it is saying that the function has three independent variables. If so, why didn't you define such a thing for the function `y`?

Comment: I edited the post to explain that stuff; hopefully it clarifies the items.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `gnuplot` to plot these. For instance, you can use the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\makeatletter\newwrite\verbatim@out\makeatother
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]
    set samples 2000 # Set to get more accurate, but slower
    set parametric
    set xtics -1,.5,1
    set ytics -1,.5,1

    set trange [-1:1] # Parametric plot range
    set xrange [-1.1:1.1] # Axis range

    set zeroaxis
    set border 0
    set xtics axis
    set ytics axis

    y(x,m,n) = (abs(1-(1-((x+1)/2)**2)**m))**n
    N(x,m,n) = (-y(0,m,n) + (y(0,m,n) - 1)*x + y(x,m,n))/(1 - 2*y(0,m,n))

    plot t,N(t,0.2,0.5) title "", t,N(t,1,5) title "", t,N(t,1,10) title ""
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

You need to compile it with the `--shell-escape` option, and have *gnuplot* installed.

As you can see in the code, it is easy to define and use functions in gnuplot, even with multiple parameters.

Rendering: 
[image: rendering of the code]

Comment: can you mark each graph on itself?

Comment: how should I render it? I have gnuplot installed on my windows. (sorry if my questions are too basic)

Comment: You can have a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46599/29394) to get gnuplottex working on Windows.

Comment: I read that question, but I am using texlive, I used the --shell-scape command, but I couldnot render that graph.

Answer (score 7):

*** Edit *** Added dashed patterns, legend and a couple of labels;
also an array `mn[]` of `(m,n)` pairs 
is used to create a function `N1(m,n)(x)`
instead of the array of functions.
[image]

```
% f.tex:
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asy}[width=8cm]
size(9cm);
import graph;
import fontsize;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));

pen dashed=linetype(new real[] {4,4});
pen longdashed=linetype(new real[] {12,4});
pen dotted=linetype(new real[] {0,3});

pen[] fpen={
  gray+longdashed,
  black+dotted,
  black+dashed
};

real y(real x,real m,real n){
  return abs(1-(1-((x+1)/2)^2)^m)^n;
}

typedef real Func(real);

Func N1(real m,real n){
  return 
    new real(real x){
      return (-y(0,m,n)+(y(0,m,n)-1)*x+y(x,m,n))/(1-2y(0,m,n));
    };
}

pair[] mn={(0.2,0.5),(1,5), (1,10)}; 

real xmin=-1, xmax=1;

xaxis(xmin,xmax,LeftTicks(Label(LeftSide),Step=0.5,step=0.1,OmitTick(0)));
yaxis(RightTicks(Step=0.5,step=0.1,OmitTick(0)));

real penwidth=1bp; 
real m,n;
for(int i=0;i<mn.length;++i){
  m=mn[i].x; n=mn[i].y;
  draw(graph(N1(m,n),xmin,xmax,n=400),fpen[i]+penwidth
    ,legend="$N_1("+string(m)+","+string(n)+")$"
  );
}

label("$x$",1.1*(xmax,0),S); // 1.1*(xmax,0) is a location,
                         // alignment S == (0,-1)  means "South"
m=mn[2].x; n=mn[2].y;

label("$("+string(m)+","+string(n)+")$",
  (0.6,N1(m,n)(0.6))
  ,SW
);

add(
  legend(linelength=0.5legendlinelength,nullpen) // here nullpen means no frame 
  ,point(NE),SW,UnFill
);
\end{asy}
\caption{Family of functions $N_1(x,m,n)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Process it as follows:

```
pdflatex f.tex
asy f-*.asy
pdflatex f.tex
```

*** ======== first version  ======== ***

[image]

Plotting of such families of functions is straightforward 
with the `Asymptote` (which is part of the `TeXLive` distribution for quite a while).
Inside the `asy` environment, the function `N1(m,n)` uses parameters `m` and 'n'
to create a new real-valued function which takes one real argument.
All functions that have to be plotted are collected in array `f[]`
and then plotted inside a loop, using a prepared array of pens `fpen[]`.

```
% f.tex:
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asy}[width=7cm]
import graph;
import fontsize;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
pen dashed=linetype(new real[] {4,4});

pen[] fpen={
  deepblue+dashed,
  black,
  orange
};

real y(real x,real m,real n){
  return abs(1-(1-((x+1)/2)^2)^m)^n;
}

typedef real Func(real);

Func N1(real m,real n){
  return 
    new real(real x){
      return (-y(0,m,n)+(y(0,m,n)-1)*x+y(x,m,n))/(1-2y(0,m,n));
    };
}

Func[] f={ N1(0.2,0.5), N1(1,5), N1(1,10) };

real xmin=-1, xmax=1;

xaxis(xmin,xmax,LeftTicks(Label(LeftSide),Step=0.5,step=0.1,OmitTick(0)));
yaxis(RightTicks(Step=0.5,step=0.1,OmitTick(0)));

real penwidth=1bp; 
for(int i=0;i<f.length;++i){
  draw(graph(f[i],xmin,xmax),fpen[i]+penwidth);
}
\end{asy}
\caption{Family of functions $N_1(x,m,n)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Process it as follows:

```
pdflatex f.tex
asy f-*.asy
pdflatex f.tex
```

P.S. I hope you don't count the step `asy f-*.asy` as too much of extra work.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to latex. Could you please help me with that process? I do not know how should I use your code. (I am really sorry if my questions are basic.)

Comment: @Parsa: Well, welcome to a new beautiful world of wanders. 
You said you are using `texlive`. It's a big system, and if it was
installed properly, then the two commands, `pdflatex` and `asy`
should be available to run from the command line (you really need
to get familiar with the command line to use `TeXLive` tools efficiently).
As for how to use the code from above: it is just a normal `LaTeX` document, 
save it into a plain text file, for example `f.tex` and process it as instructed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I processed the plot and it worked indeed. I copied the TeX file, opened the TeXLive command and went to the directory of the TeX file and processed those three commands. No I have the plot.

Comment: I have two questions, How should I make those lines dashed, dotted, etc. Because my thesis is not color printed and I have to use those styles. and also, the PDF output is an A4 with lots of margins, how should I reduce those margins to easily include them in my main TeX file? and how should I label the axises?

Comment: An also how to label each line in that plot. something like legend or label on each line.

Comment: And one last, can I plot 3d plots with that package?

Comment: @Parsa: I'm sure that there are many options you might want to adjust
in your images, so I'd suggest you to run a command `texdoc asymptote` from the command line,
then you can find out all (well, most of) the details. For example,
dashed pen used was constructed with a line `pen dashed=linetype(new real[] {4,4});`
Experiment with the numbers in the real array to get the dashed/dotted patterns of your taste,
or just use a predefined patterns.

Comment: @Parsa:Check out examples on labels and legends in the doc.
One suggestion that might be important and can possibly save a lot of time:
when using the `[inline]` `asy` code, 
make sure to remove all of the intermediate files when changing the code inside
the `asy` environment. And yes, you can plot `3d` images with the `Asymptote`
(again, see the docs).

Comment: Your answer was great. Thank you so much for your answer and comments. You really helped me.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I can not add any legend to that code... :(

Comment: @Enthusiastic Student: see updated version.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun with PSTricks. Compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex` twice.

```
% filename.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{graph.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{fourier}

\def\y[#1,#2,#3]{(abs(1-(1-((#1+1)/2)^2)^#2)^#3)}
\def\N[#1,#2,#3]{(-\y[0,#2,#3]+(\y[0,#2,#3]-1)*(#1)+\y[#1,#2,#3])/(1-2*\y[0,#2,#3])}
\psset
{
 algebraic,
 plotpoints=500,
 llx=-15pt,
 lly=-15pt,
 urx=15pt,
 ury=15pt,
 xAxisLabel=$x$,
 yAxisLabel=$y$,
 subticks=10,
 subtickcolor=red,
}


\begin{document}
\pslegend[lt]
{
    \color{red}\rule{2cm}{2pt}      & \color{red} $N[x,0.2,0.5]$\\
    \color{green}\rule{2cm}{2pt}    & \color{green} $N[x,1,5]$\\
    \color{blue}\rule{2cm}{2pt}     & \color{blue} $N[x,1,10]$
}
\begin{psgraph}[axespos=top,Dx=0.5,Dy=0.5](0,0)(-1.5,-0.75)(1.5,1.5){12cm}{!}
    \foreach \am/\wn/\cl in {0.2/0.5/red,1/5/green,1/10/blue}{\psplot[linecolor=\cl,yMaxValue=6]{-1}{1}{\N[x,\am,\wn]}}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{latex graph && dvips graph && ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None graph.ps}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{graph}%
\caption{This is the family of mine $N[x,m,n]$.}
\label{fig:plot}
\end{figure}
See my plot on page~\pageref{fig:plot}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193817/52417) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193670/how-to-plot-a-complicated-multi-variable-function-in-a-tex-document-automaticall), I renderred my plot as follows (Thanks to [Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1537/christian-feuers%c3%a4nger)). I chose this answer because it was easy for me as a basic user of the LaTeX and it was easier for me tounderstand the process, functions, codes, etc. Also, it is capable of defining different functions and customizable indeed.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt, convert={size=640x}]{standalone}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \directlua{
        Y = function(x,m,n)
            return math.abs(1-(1-((x+1)/2)^2)^m)^n
        end
        N1 = function(x,m,n)
            return (-Y(0,m,n) + (Y(0,m,n)-1)*x + Y(x,m,n))/ (1-2*Y(0,m,n))
        end
    }
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{N1}{3}{%
        \edef\pgfmathresult{\directlua{tex.print(N1(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#2},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#3}))}}%
    }%
    \begin{axis}
    [
    grid=major,
    axis lines=center,
    enlargelimits,
    tick align=inside,
    cycle list ={solid,dotted,dashed},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.05)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        legend entries={$m=1,n=1$\\$m=1,n=5$\\$m=1,n=10$\\},
    domain=-1:0.99999,
    samples=200,
    minor tick num=5,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$N_{AG - 3}^{\left( 1 \right)}$
    ]

    \addplot {N1(x,1,1)};
    \addplot {N1(x,1,5)};
    \addplot {N1(x,1,10)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]