# Parametric plot using pgfplots package

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

I want to make a parametric plot using pgfplot in LaTex. My equations are

`\rho= K (sinh t-t)`
`P= 1/3 K (sinh t - 8 sinh (1/2) t +3t)`
with `K=1\pi`

I have written the LaTex code for equations , now please help me plot the graph

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin {document}

\underline {Chandrashekhar EOS (1935)} : \\
\begin{align*}
\overline \rho &= K ~\Big( \sinh ~t ~- ~t\Big)\\
\overline P &= \frac {1}{3} K ~ \Big(\sinh~t -~ 8~ \sinh \frac {1}{2} t  +~ 3t\Big)\\
 K &= \frac {1}{4\pi}\\
\end {align*}
\end {document}
```

Comment: You should have a look in the [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), specifically section 4.3.3 on page 51 of the v1.10 manual. You also appear to have some differences between the formula in the LaTeX code and the first one... specifically, `K=1/pi` and `K=1/(4*pi)`

Comment: Don't use `~` in math mode; the spacing you get is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another fun with PSTricks. It really uses the parametric approach in question.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math,amsmath}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\XMin{0-6}
\FPeval\XMax{7}
\FPeval\YMin{0-6}
\FPeval\YMax{6}

\FPeval\XOL{0-1/3} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\XOR{1/3} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\YOB{0-1/3} % of DeltaY
\FPeval\YOT{1/3} % of DeltaY

%\FPset\TrigLabelBase{3}
\FPeval\DeltaX{1}
\FPeval\DeltaY{1}

\FPeval\AxisL{XMin+DeltaX*XOL}
\FPeval\AxisR{XMax+DeltaX*XOR}
\FPeval\AxisB{YMin+DeltaY*YOB}
\FPeval\AxisT{YMax+DeltaY*YOT}

\newlength\Width\Width=12cm


\newlength\llx\llx=-5pt
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-5pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt


\psset
{
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    %xtrigLabels,
    %ytrigLabels,
    %trigLabelBase=\TrigLabelBase,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=500,
    yMaxValue=\YMax,
    yMinValue=\YMin,
}

\pstVerb{/K {.25 Pi div} def}
\def\x{t}
\def\yp{K*(SINH(t)-t)}
\def\yP{K/3*(SINH(t)-8*SINH(t/2)+3*t)}




\begin{document}
\pslegend[bt](80,0)
{
    \color{NavyBlue}\rule{12pt}{3pt} & \color{NavyBlue} $\overline{p} = K (\sinh t -t) $ \\
    \color{Maroon}\rule{12pt}{3pt}   & \color{Maroon} $\overline{P} = \tfrac{1}{3} K (\sinh t -8 \sinh (\tfrac{1}{2}t)+3t) $ \\
                                     & where $K=\frac{1}{4\pi}$
}
\begin{psgraph}
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        Dy=\DeltaY,
        Dx=\DeltaX,
        linecolor=gray,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-3pt 3pt,
        axespos=top,
    ]{<->}(0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}
    \psaxes
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        labels=none,
        subticks=5,
        tickwidth=.4pt,
        subtickwidth=.2pt,
        tickcolor=Red!30,
        subtickcolor=ForestGreen!30,
        xticksize=\YMin\space \YMax,
        yticksize=\XMin\space \XMax,
        subticksize=1,
    ](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{\XMin}{7}{\x|\yp}
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=Maroon]{\XMin}{7}{\x|\yP}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes for ShareLaTeX users

Go to upper left menu, and you will see the following. Change as pointed by the red arrow. And don't forget to recompile.

[image]

### The lastest update based on OP's comment

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math,amsmath}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% Be careful, fp has not defined 
% the unary negate so we have to write 0-8 to represent -8 for example.

\FPeval\XMin{0-0}
\FPeval\XMax{7}
\FPeval\YMin{0-0}
\FPeval\YMax{6}

\FPeval\XOL{0-0} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\XOR{1/3} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\YOB{0-0} % of DeltaY
\FPeval\YOT{1/3} % of DeltaY

%\FPset\TrigLabelBase{3}
\FPeval\DeltaX{1}
\FPeval\DeltaY{1}

\FPeval\AxisL{XMin+DeltaX*XOL}
\FPeval\AxisR{XMax+DeltaX*XOR}
\FPeval\AxisB{YMin+DeltaY*YOB}
\FPeval\AxisT{YMax+DeltaY*YOT}

\newlength\Width\Width=12cm


\newlength\llx\llx=-20pt
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-20pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt


\psset
{
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    %xtrigLabels,
    %ytrigLabels,
    %trigLabelBase=\TrigLabelBase,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=500,
    yMaxValue=\YMax,
    yMinValue=\YMin,
}

\pstVerb{/K {.25 Pi div} def}
\def\x{t}
\def\yp{K*(SINH(t)-t)}
\def\yP{K/3*(SINH(t)-8*SINH(t/2)+3*t)}




\begin{document}
\pslegend[rt]%(80,0)
{
    \color{NavyBlue}\rule{12pt}{3pt} & \color{NavyBlue} $\overline{p} = K (\sinh t -t) $ \\
    \color{Maroon}\rule{12pt}{3pt} & \color{Maroon} $\overline{P} = \tfrac{1}{3} K (\sinh t -8 \sinh (\tfrac{1}{2}t)+3t) $ \\
    & where $K=\frac{1}{4\pi}$
}
\begin{psgraph}
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        Dy=\DeltaY,
        Dx=\DeltaX,
        linecolor=gray,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-3pt 3pt,
        axespos=top,
    ]{->}(0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}
    \psaxes
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        labels=none,
        subticks=5,
        tickwidth=.4pt,
        subtickwidth=.2pt,
        tickcolor=Red!30,
        subtickcolor=ForestGreen!30,
        xticksize=\YMin\space \YMax,
        yticksize=\XMin\space \XMax,
        subticksize=1,
    ](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{\XMin}{7}{\x|\yp}
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=Maroon]{\XMin}{7}{\x|\yP}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: he wants a plot with `K=1/π`

Comment: thanks all for your nice effort, but I am using sharelatex.com to type my documents. is there any way I can set the graph in my document directly coding in sharelatex?

Comment: @TazkeraHaqueTrina I have no experience to typeset at that site, but; as you can run the codes I provided in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195330/52417) in-line with your other codes and documents and you need no further package run or special permeable; so I do not think you have any special issue using them. Copy my second part of answer which is edited to work in `pdflatex` (not the `lua` part) and render your file. I don't think you have any issue.

Comment: the last thing to know, what changes should I make to the code to transfer the axis from center to left margin, I really need to show the +x and +y axis there, not the negative axes. thanks

Comment: @TazkeraHaqueTrina: See my update and thanks for accepting this answer. The downvoters might be angry. :-)

Comment: @TazkeraHaqueTrina See the update to my answer too.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch :))) poor downvoters! Congratulations for accepted answer. You have very good knowledge of TeX indeed.

Comment: @Enthusistic Student, I have already upvoted your post. I am always grateful o people helping me. thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

**Note**: Other answers to this question may use other `k`s for plotting (eg. K=1/4π). In my answer, I have used question's desired `k` value which is `K=1/π`. That is why there may be a slight difference in the plots.

---

You can plot your functions with [`pgfplots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/). Run the following code with `LuaLaTeX`, I have used it to avoid probable numerical inaccuracies.

```
% lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\directlua{
    R= function(x,k)
    return k*(math.sinh(x)-x)
    end

    P = function(x,k)
    return k*(math.sinh(x)- 8*math.sinh(x/2)+3*x)/3
    end
        }
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{R}{2}{%
            \edef\pgfmathresult{\directlua{tex.print(R(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#2}))}}%
        }%
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{P}{2}{%
            \edef\pgfmathresult{\directlua{tex.print(P(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1},\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#2}))}}%
        }%
\begin{axis}
        [
    axis lines = center,
    grid=both,minor tick num=1,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    tick align=inside,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=1},
        legend entries={${\rho}= K\Big(\sinh t-t\Big)$\\$P= \frac{1}{3}K\Big(\sinh t-8\sinh\frac {1}{2} t  + 3t\Big)$\\},
        domain=-6:6,
        samples=60,
        ]
        \addplot [solid, thick] {R(x,1/pi)};
       \addplot [dashed, thick] {P(x,1/pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here is the output:
[image]

P.S. Other answers exists for plotting parametric/complicated functions in this question: [How to plot a complicated multi-variable function in a tex document automatically, not just importing an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193670/how-to-plot-a-complicated-multi-variable-function-in-a-tex-document-automaticall)

---

**update**: If you don't want to use the `LuaLaTeX`, here is another version of my answer which is suggested in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195319/parametric-plot-using-pgfplots-package/195330#comment451967_195330):

```
% pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{R}{2}{\pgfmathparse{#2 * (sinh(#1) - #1)}}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{P}{2}{\pgfmathparse{#2 * (sinh(#1) - 8*sinh(#1/2) + 3*#1)/3}}
\begin{axis}
        [
    axis lines = center,
    grid=both,minor tick num=1,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    tick align=inside,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=1},
        legend entries={${\rho}= K\Big(\sinh t-t\Big)$\\$P= \frac{1}{3}K\Big(\sinh t-8\sinh\frac {1}{2} t  + 3t\Big)$\\},
        domain=0:10,
        samples=60,
        ]
        \addplot [solid, thick] {R(x,1/pi)};
       \addplot [dashed, thick] {P(x,1/pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output (it is optimized to show the positive axis only, change the `domain` to any value you need):

[image]

Comment: Good answer! Note that `        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{R}{2}{\pgfmathparse{#2 * (sinh(#1) - #1)}}` and `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{P}{2}{\pgfmathparse{#2 * (sinh(#1) - 8*sinh(#1/2) + 3*#1)/3}}` would also do the job - the PGF math engine can compute it with good precision.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Thanks... I did not know that. I also updated my answer to include that point.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with PSTricks, run with `xelatex`. The parametricplot P(t)=f(rho(t)) seems to be a line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}
\begin {document}

\begin{align*}
\overline{\rho}&= K\left(\sinh t-t\right)\\
\overline{P}   &= \frac{1}{3}K\left(\sinh t-8\sinh\frac{1}{2}t+ 3t\right)\\
             K &= \frac{1}{4\pi}
\end {align*}

\psset{llx=-15mm,lly=-5mm,urx=5mm,ury=5mm,algebraic,yMaxValue=7,
  plotpoints=500,xAxisLabel=$t$,yAxisLabel={},ticks=none}
\begin{psgraph}[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,psgrid,gridcoor={(7,7)}]{->}(0,0)(7,7){10cm}{10cm}
\pstVerb{ /K 1 4 PI mul div def }
\psplot[linecolor=blue,arrows=-]{0}{7}{ K*(SINH(x)-x) }
\psplot[linecolor=red,arrows=-]{0}{7}{ K/3*(SINH(x)-8*SINH(x/2)+3*x) }
\psparametricplot[linewidth=1.5pt,arrows=-]{0}{5.2}{ K*(SINH(t)-t) | K/3*(SINH(t)-8*SINH(t/2)+3*t) }
\rput[rb](4.5,4.5){\blue$\overline{\rho}=K\left(\sinh t-t\right)$}
\rput[lb](0.5,2.5){\red$\overline{P}=\frac{1}{3}K\left(\sinh t-8\sinh\frac{1}{2}t+3t\right)$}
\uput[0](0,7){$\overline{P}$}\uput[180](0,7){$\overline{\rho}$}
\uput*[90](1.5,0.5){$\overline{P}=f(\overline{\rho})$}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For sharelatex copy this one into a new projekt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}
\begin {document}

\psset{llx=-15mm,lly=-5mm,urx=5mm,ury=5mm,algebraic,yMaxValue=7,
  plotpoints=500,xAxisLabel=$t$,yAxisLabel={}}
\begin{psgraph}[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(7,7){10cm}{10cm}
\pstVerb{ /K 1 4 PI mul div def }
\psplot[linecolor=blue,arrows=-]{0}{7}{ K*(SINH(x)-x) }
\psplot[linecolor=red,arrows=-]{0}{7}{ K/3*(SINH(x)-8*SINH(x/2)+3*x) }
\psparametricplot[linewidth=1.5pt,arrows=-]{0}{5.2}{ K*(SINH(t)-t) | K/3*(SINH(t)-8*SINH(t/2)+3*t) }
\rput[rb](4.5,4.5){\blue$\overline{\rho}=K\left(\sinh t-t\right)$}
\rput[lb](0.5,2.5){\red$\overline{P}=\frac{1}{3}K\left(\sinh t-8\sinh\frac{1}{2}t+3t\right)$}
\uput[0](0,7){$\overline{P}$}\uput[180](0,7){$\overline{\rho}$}
\uput*[90](1.5,0.5){$\overline{P}=f(\overline{\rho})$}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Then choose from the menu (top left) the compiler `xelatex`. However, sharelatex is not a good choice it doesn't update the TeX distribution.

Comment: How can i get this graph in sharelatex.com , as I was typing my document there, also It would have been better if you take the axis to the left margin instead of center. thanks for your nice effort

Comment: See my edited answer. At the end is a version for sharelatex.