# gnuplottex with windows 8.1

Tags: miktex, texmaker, windows, gnuplot

I am having difficulties setting up my system right in order to add the `gnuplottex` abbility. I followed this tutorial: [adding gnuplot capability to latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45366/adding-gnuplot-capability-to-latex/46599#46599) and also used the mwe posted in this thread. In addition to that, I have spent quite some time researching without figuring out what the problem is.

I am using *windows 8.1*, *miktex 2.9*, *texmaker 4.2* and *gnuplot 4.6*. I have added the command `--enable-write18` to the pdflatex command and also tried different versions I have read about.

While compiling the mwe a warning is shown for a short moment about not finding the commands `touch` and `rm`. There is an entry in the log-file:

```
\verbatim@out=\write3
runsystem(touch w18-test-20148448.tex)...executed.

runsystem(rm -f w18-test-20148448.tex)...executed.


Package gnuplottex Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
(gnuplottex)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself..
```

Does anybody know a solution how to add the abbility to compile `gnuplottex` codes with my system setup? Every and any hint is appreciated.

Thats how i enabled shell escape in TexMaker:
[image]

Comment: I never used `gnuplottex` at all, but `touch` and `rm` are UNIX/Linux commands, at least in their origins. Perhaps you have to use cygwin or install the gnu environment to use this package or at least portions of it. The true error seems to be, that `--enable-write18` does not work for your setup, perhaps due to security restrictions.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have never used a Linux system and I am not familiar with these commands. I have tried to install cygwin once. for some reason it failed. how do I install the gnu environment? or do you have any idea how to come accros this security restrictions?

Comment: @HarishKumar How do i enable `-shell-escape` **while** compiling?

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, I am using _Texmaker 4.2_. Could you post I line of code I can include into the mwe?

Comment: @HarishKumar I added a print screen of how I added the `--enable-write18` command. I tried like variations like `-enable-write18`, `-shell-escape` and `--shell-escape`. nothing worked so far.

Comment: You gave to use `PDFLaTeX` from drop down menu, not `Quickbuild`. and leave a space after `--enable-write18`.

Comment: Where is the difference, if `Quickbuild` is set to `PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf`? Anyway, using `PdfLaTeX` from the drop down menu does not work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @millo Did you pass the option miktex to gnuplottex? This changes the executed commands that work on Linux/Mac to Windows specific syntax.

Comment: @John If I pass the option `miktex` with the command `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}`, the `rm` and `touch` commands do not seem the problem anymore. But there is still something going wrong. The log file includes the lines:  `Opening gnuplot stream gnuplot-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot runsystem(gnuplot gnuplot-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot)...executed.

Package gnuplottex Warning: Conversion of gnuplot-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot failed.

Package gnuplottex Warning: Please convert gnuplot-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot manually.`  Is this an improvement or a step backwards?

Comment: @millo Forward. Can you please send me an email containing the relevant tex-file and your log-file? I am the co-author of gnuplottex (second email adress mentioned in http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.pdf )

Comment: @John The email is sent. Please let me know if you did not get it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by using `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}` and by deactivating the `Use a "build" subdirectory for output files` option by Texmaker