# Gnuplottex is not working

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplottex

I've tried that example [how to use gnuplottex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311460/how-to-use-gnuplottex)

In a new document and I get gnuplottex package working, however, when I include gnuplottex package in my project doesn't work properly and it is the package because when I remove it does work fine. With package loaded I get that message:

```
! Package catchfile Error: File `<projectname>.gnuploterrors' not found.
```

and this one:

```
Runaway argument?
\ifx \gnuploterrors@ \@empty \else \PackageWarningNoLine {gnuplottex}\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \gnuploterrors@eatpar.
```

Does anyone use gnuplottex usually? Thank you so much!

Comment: The error appears if you have no `gnuplot` environment in the document. You find a workaround in the link.

Comment: So sorry for duplicate, but thank you so much :)

Comment: Don't worry, I just happened to remember the other question.