# Tree in tikz, with triangles standing for sub-trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I need to draw a tree in tikz similar to this one:

[image: A tree]

What I CAN'T DO is drawing the dashed triangle leaves (standing for unspecified subtrees).
I think I can manage to draw the legend by myself, and am working on it. Any hint or idea?

Here is a MWE showing what I did so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=5cm, level 2/.style={sibling distance =2cm}]
\node[circle,draw,fill=black] {}
    child{ node[circle, fill = black] {}
            child{ node[circle, draw] {}
                        child{ node {Q1} } 
                }
            child{ node[rectangle, fill = black] {}
                    child {
                        node[rectangle, fill = black] {}
                            child{ node {Q2} }
                            child { node[circle,draw] {} 
                                    child { node {Q3} }                         
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
    child{ node[circle, draw] {}
            child{ node {Q4} }
            child{node {Q5} }       
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try to work with "isosceles triangle" like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7862/triangle-node-with-adjustable-height and define special shapes for the left and right shifted triangles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's another option using variations of the `isosceles triangle` shape:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
itria/.style={
  draw,dashed,shape border uses incircle,
  isosceles triangle,shape border rotate=90,yshift=-1.45cm},
rtria/.style={
  draw,dashed,shape border uses incircle,
  isosceles triangle,isosceles triangle apex angle=90,
  shape border rotate=-45,yshift=0.2cm,xshift=0.5cm},
ritria/.style={
  draw,dashed,shape border uses incircle,
  isosceles triangle,isosceles triangle apex angle=110,
  shape border rotate=-55,yshift=0.1cm},
letria/.style={
  draw,dashed,shape border uses incircle,
  isosceles triangle,isosceles triangle apex angle=110,
  shape border rotate=235,yshift=0.1cm}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=5cm, level 2/.style={sibling distance =2cm}]
\node[circle,draw,fill=black] {}
    child{ node[circle, fill = black] {}
            child{ node[circle, draw] {}
                        { node[itria] {Q1} } 
                }
            child{ node[rectangle, fill = black] {}
                    child {
                        node[rectangle, fill = black] {}
                            child{ node[rtria] {Q2} }
                            child { node[circle,draw] {} 
                                     { node[itria] {Q3} }                         
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
    child{ node[circle, draw] {}
            child{ node[ritria] {Q4} }
            child{node[letria] {Q5} }       
        };
\node[draw] at (3,-5) 
{
\begin{tabular}{cl}
\tikz\node[circle,fill] {}; & branching \\
\tikz\node[circle,draw] {}; & jump \\
\tikz\node[rectangle,fill] {}; & unary
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the `ritria` and `letria` styles, I find `isosceles triangle apex angle=110,` with corresponding tweaks `xshift` and `yshift` closer to picture posted by OP.

Comment: @hpesoj626 yes, you're right; I've introduced the mnodification in my updated answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, when you can find a way how to commit the node names to the new defined shapes, we are close to what you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\pgfdeclareshape{left triangle}{
    \nodeparts{}
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
    \behindbackgroundpath{
    \path [draw,dashed] (0,0) -- (0,-2) -- (-1,-2) -- cycle;
   }
}
\pgfdeclareshape{right triangle}{
    \nodeparts{}
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
    \behindbackgroundpath{
    \path [draw,dashed] (0,0) -- (0,-2) -- (1,-2) -- cycle;
   }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
sibling distance=5cm, 
level 2/.style={sibling distance =2cm},
triangle/.style={isosceles triangle,draw,shape border rotate=90, dashed, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=15mm, inner sep=0},
]
\node[circle,draw,fill=black] {}
    child{ node[circle, fill = black] {}
            child{ node[circle, draw] {}
                        child{ node[triangle] {Q1} } 
                }
            child{ node[rectangle, fill = black] {}
                    child {
                        node[rectangle, fill = black] {}
                            child{ node[left triangle] {Q2} }
                            child { node[circle,draw] {} 
                                   child{node[triangle] {Q3}}
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
    child{ node[circle, draw] {}
            child{node[left triangle] {Q4} }
            child{node[right triangle] {Q5} }       
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I prefer the other one because it has no edges for the triangle nodes.